# Error using SessionStorageService with CustomAuthenticationStateProvider Blazor .net 8

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm trying to use the SessionStorageService within a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider
but the following error occurs when the AuthorizeView tag is activated:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.'
```

When logging in, it works perfectly, as this part is already loaded. My application is Blazor Server with .net 8.

How can I make the Home that uses the AuthorizeView tag able to use SessionStorage?

Thank you.

**CustomAuthentication:**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorageService;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService)
    {
        _sessionStorageService = sessionStorageService;
    }


    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = await _sessionStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("token");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(_anonymous);
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt");
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return new AuthenticationState(_anonymous);
        }
    }

    public void AuthenticateUser(string token)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var state = new AuthenticationState(user);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
    }
}
```

**Home.razor**

```
@inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService SessionStorage
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using UI.Web.Admin.Identity.Pages

@page "/"


<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        Welcome to your new app.
    </Authorized>

    <NotAuthorized>
        <LoginForm />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

**Program**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
         .AddInteractiveServerComponents();


    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();



    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AuthService>(options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["ApiUrl"]);
    });




    var app = builder.Build();




    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAntiforgery();

    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();


    app.Run();
}
```

**App.Razor**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="UI.Web.Admin.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>...</NotFound>
    </Router>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, ISessionStorageService  uses  IStorageProvider  that injects IJSRuntime which is configured by Blazor framework. The lifetime for IJSRuntime is scoped so you will be always hitting this error on refresh.  I checked and Blazored  lib and the give no option for configuration. Why not just disable prerender or set up If condition that is true after first render, and wraps Authorize view ?

Comment: @ArturChrzanowski To be honest, I don't know how to do this. No information on the internet matches the current version of .net 8.
Lots of changes and no content I can reproduce.

I just need to have a way to access this SessionStorage on the serverside. I don't need pre render.

I tried doing the same code in a webassembly version and it looks even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I assume that you don' t care about prerender, therefore I will give code below to disable it so you wont' encounter JS error anymore.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="UI.Web.Admin.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)"/>
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)"/>
   
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the important line : @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" . Be aware that all your components from now on will be server rendered with disabled prerender. Rest is unchanged.

Routes Is the standard component included in blazor template.

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

I hope this will help you. If you have any other question to ask, feel free to do so.